# SCCM Update Restart Notification Configuration

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, sccm, sccm-2012-r2

My line manager wants us to push out the 1903 feature upgrade to computers, but he wants them to have a notification about the restart which looks as below and allows the user to delay the restart. He also expects the user to be able to restart the computer without the update installing until they have selected this in software centre.

The screen he is talking about looks as below:

[image: reboot notification]

Our client settings look as below:

[image]

The deployment options are as below:

[image]

[image]

I’d be very grateful if anyone is able to advise on what we would need to change in order to get the desired effect. Sorry to ask about this as I am really stuck.